# Create sub-document dynamically by jquery

Tags: jquery

I know one way to create the following sub-document dynamically by Jquery. That is first create individual element by document.createElement(), then add its corresponding class and attributes and finally join the elements by append method.

But I want to know is there any easier way to create the whole sub-document dynamically.

```
.card
    .card-block
        .row
            .col-11
                .card-title
                    h5 Group Name:
                    p Task Title:
                    each value, index in array
                        span.member.mr-3 !{value}
                            a.remove.ml-2(href='javascript:;' title="Remove" data-index=index)
                                i.fa.fa-times(aria-hidden="true")
                     a.newMember(type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#memberModal" href='javascript:;' title="Add")
                         i.fa.fa-plus(aria-hidden="true")
                    br
                    div.mt-3
                        a(href='') Discussion
                        a.ml-3(href='') Documnets
        .col-1
            a.delete(href='javascript:;' title="Delete" data-index=i)
               i.fa.fa-trash(aria-hidden="true")
```

Comment: What you mean by _dynamically_ ?

Comment: Dynamically means changes occur without loading the page.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery allows you to specify all the attributes and properties of an object when creating it, using an object containing the mappings:

```
$("<a>", {
    "class": "delete",
    "href": "javascript:;",
    "title": "Delete",
    "data": {
        "index": i
    }
})
```